# Forwarding mail from Cloudflare through Mailgun

Tags: cloudflare, mailgun

I have a domain that is run through Cloudflare.  I want to receive custom emails for my domain such as hi@domain.com.  I want those emails to be forwarded to my personal gmail address.

I set up Mailgun with my domain, and it verified the MX, TXT, and CNAME records are set up correctly at Cloudflare.  I set up a route on Mailgun to forward any mail sent to my domain to my personal gmail account. However, I am still not receiving email send to hi@domain.com.

I have set up mailgun using the recommended domain mg.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue that turned out to be related to the Spam Experts system, called Professional Spam Filter in Cpanel. Within that subsystem under Incoming there is an Edit Route. That needed to be changed from the domain name to the Server name  (name of the host server).

I tested it on two different domains and it worked instantly.